# How to disable doxygen markup

Tags: doxygen, markup

I would like to disable all doxygen markup handling (in my function header). I've read through all the doxygen options (in doxywizard) but can't seem to find the option. Does it exist?

EG:

```
/** -------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function    : <INIT> 
            : \Test
Purpose     : @50Hz
*/
```

None of the characters in the description above should trigger markup handling (@, \, <>, etc).

Comment: Couldn't find a solution for this one. Had to strip all the source code manually with regular expressions :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap any text you want to appear verbatim in the [verbatim](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdverbatim)/[endverbatim](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdendverbatim) tags.

```
/**    -------------------------------------------------------------------------
\verbatim 
    Function    : <INIT> 
                : \Test Purpose     : @50Hz 
\endverbatim
*/
```